# How do I remove view right to the editor in Eclipse pydev perspective?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

My environment is Eclipse Luna 4.4 and pydev 3.7.

To the right of the editor, there is a view that I want to turn off. A screenshot is posted at the following link.

[image]

I tried adjusting various preferences like range indicator but can't figure out how to remove the view.

Few questions:

1. What is this view and how is it used?
2. What do the two bars in the view represent?
3. How do I remove this view?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25594935/2670892

Comment: That's the minimap (which was made default in pydev 3.7). Follow the link from greg to see how to revert to the old style -- as a note, this is an overview ruler replacement (the lines there represent items from the outline).

Answer (score 10):

In the `Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap` you need to uncheck below box.

`Show minimap?(applied on editor restart)`

And then restart you eclipse for the changes to take place. The minimap is so boring and that too with pink color. I hate it.

Answer (score 6):

This is controlled by Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap