# Where is classical vertical scrollbar in PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, windows, pydev

I have just updated Eclipse (using with PyDev) and surprisingly found out that the classic vertical scrollbar is changed to some strange thing as marked on the figure (screenshot).

[image]

Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

I would like to ask you how can I disable this or change it back to classical vertical scrollbar in editor in Eclipse?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is the Overview Ruler Minimap which is now the default with PyDev release 3.7.0

This is controlled by Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap

Comment: Solved it. I was a little confused as when I changed to Java perspective (from pydev) this Overview Ruler Minimap was still shown when python file was opened. That is why I was only looking in Preferences > General > Editors. I have also updated pydev to release 3.7.0.

Comment: My mouse scroll wheel wouldn't work until "Show vertical scrollbar" was checked.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap.

There is an option "Show vertical scrollbar?"

disable it :)

[image]

Comment: Uncheck "Show minimap?" and check "Show vertical scrollbar?". This should revert the classical eclipse scrollbar.