# What's the funny pane to the right of the PyDev editor window?

Tags: pydev

[Where is classical vertical scrollbar in PyDev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594935/where-is-classical-vertical-scrollbar-in-eclipse) tells how to remove this feature, but does not answer my question:

I'm new to Python and PyDev. There's a funny pane just to the right of the Python editor view in Eclipse. Someone went to a lot of trouble to create it. I sort of see what it's doing, but I'm at a loss as to why I would want it or what use real Python programmers make of it.

[image]

Comment: I am not an Eclipse user, but this looks like `minimap` to me. This is a default feature in Sublime Text, but extensions are now available for Vim and Emacs. As a programmer, I think it is useful to me for 2 reasons, first, it gives me wider navigational click/mouse region for scrolling; second, when I search for something in a long file, it tells me how many occurrences are in the file.

Comment: Ah, very good to know! I sort of got the "wider navigation" concept, didn't know about occurrences. Promote your comment to an answer and I'll accept it. (Yes, it is called minimap.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an Eclipse user, but this looks like `minimap` to me. This is a default feature in Sublime Text, but extensions are now available for Vim and Emacs.

As a programmer, I think it is useful to me for 2 reasons, first, it gives me wider navigational click/mouse region for scrolling; second, when I search for something in a long file, it tells me how many occurrences are in the file.

Since this is an answer, I think I should add few more reasons to use minimap that sorta kinda make sense to me. Take a look at discussion here, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156362/does-sublimes-minimap-improve-productivity

[I found another reason](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/proper_way_to_use_Sublime_Text_minimap.html), but seems like a put-off idea. I have never written my code this way and will never write it.