# What information is this column in the Eclipse editor showing me?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, perspective

I just moved a Python project into Eclipse, and I don't understand what this column (encircled in red) is trying to indicate to me:

[image: Eclipse Editor Screenshot]

I get that the blue rectangle is a sliding window that corresponds to the code section currently in the window, but what do the grey lines mean?

Other Information:
 - I have used previous versions of Eclipse and PyDev and haven't seen this before. Even now, I only see it when I open a open a PyDev project. I assume it's some option associated with the PyDev perspective, but I can't find any option in the Customize Perspective menu for it.
 - I have looked through several Eclipse tutorials and help files, and can't find any other examples of it.
 - The grey lines don't seem to correspond to function calls, indentation, docstrings/comments, or any other code trait that I can think of.
 - I am using Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler) with PyDev 1.0.0.9.

Note: The code shown is from the [python-graph library](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/). Copyright is held by the creators of that library.

Comment: It is the pydev Overview Ruler Minimap http://stackoverflow.com/q/25594935/2670892

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the name! Now I at least have a term to search for. Unfortunately, I still can't seem to find any anything about what it's actually telling me. I see that if I select an identifier, it will show me where else in the file it's used. But I still have no idea what the lines mean when nothing is selected and there are no annotations present. All I can find is information about how to enable/disable it or change its appearance.