# How to remove eclipse strange white bars?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, themes

The white bars as shown come to my eclipse today accidently, I have no ideas to change the color of it or hide it. I also have tried reset the folding, but it did not help.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Try rebooting eclipse?

Comment: Looks like it's just not rendering the scrollbars. Try forcing it to repaint by resizing the window or dragging another window over it.

Comment: Who ever downvoted, please add your comments.

Comment: Try to disable overview toolbar and  check. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594935/where-is-classical-vertical-scrollbar-in-eclipse

Comment: @KyleEmmerich  Thank you!!! Solved it! 