# Eclipse overview ruler don't show all text

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've searched for answers to this problem for days now, and still no solution.

The problem is: I work with eclipse and pydev in linux environment and in the overview ruler I only see lines that represent function definitions and imports, all other text in my .py file (or any other file for that matter) is now shown.

I tried to see annotations and other properties and that does not change a thing.

I'm adding a picture with the problem:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25594935/2670892

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue is that this feature is not currently implemented in PyDev. The overview ruler as it is is not a real minimap. It only shows entries for what would be outline entries (not a minimap for the code).

Comment: but in the c/c++ editor i still see the same minimap .
how can it be?

Comment: This probably means you're using LiClipse (all LiClipse-based editors use the same foundation that PyDev uses).

Comment: how can i know if this is eclipse or lilclipse ??

because when i do help->about eclipse : 
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: You can right-click the editor > Open with and see which dropdown options appear (and the current one).

Comment: it shows me a variety of options : c/c++ editor,python editor etc.
no indication of eclipse or lilclipse.